# Tengo problemas con una consulta en mysql ayuda!

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de biblioteca programado en php y dentro de ese sistema tengo un buscador para visualizar los libros. El programa ya hace una búsqueda básica y me muestra resultados pero algunos campos ya no corresponden, el problema o más bien la duda es como puedo hacer  una consulta ejemplo:

- DB:mydb
- Table1: título,fecha,edición,etc
- Table2: carrera
- Table3: categoria
- Table4. editorial.

como hago para que al ingresar carrera titulo categoria, editorial,

- Ejemplo1: buscar por: ingeniería, y que se muestren todos los libros correspondientes a esta búsqueda que se ingresó,
- Ejemplo2: Buscar por: Titulo,y se muestren todos los libros por titulo y con la carrera a la que pertenecen, y así lo mismo con las tablas categoría y editorial, con la tabla 1 no tengo problema pero con las otras si que hago ayuda por favor!!!

Comment: ¿Todas las tablas se relacionaría sólo con la tabla libros o algunas tendrían relaciones entre sí?

Comment: tengo una tabla que se llama idficha y dentro de esta estan todos los id de las otras tablas Ej: idtable1, idtable2, idtable3 idtable4 y esas cuatro tablas tienen relacion con la tabla idficha que es donde estan relacionadas las 4 tablas.

Comment: @KevinDuarte Es el título de pregunta más descriptivo que he visto en mi vida...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este diseño podría resolver tu problema. Ya que no das más detalles he considerado que todas las tablas se relacionan con la tabla libros.

Para entender el diseño: **se mantienen todos los datos por separado, cada uno en su tabla**, y **se unen a través de una tabla asociativa** por los ids respectivos, eso permite tener en la tabla asociativa relaciones de *uno a varios* por ejemplo, el caso de que un mismo libro pueda pertenecer a varias categorías o a varias editoriales, o a varias carreras, etc. Esto evitará además la existencia de datos redundantes (repetidos) en cada una de las tablas.

En el ejemplo hay dos modelos de consulta, una general y otra por carrera, puedes filtrar por lo que quieras, cambiando el `WHERE`que va después de los `JOIN`:

**Nota:** El modelo muestra más o menos la estructura de las tablas, si te decides por él le agregas a cada una las columnas que falten, las claves primarias, los índices, etc. En cuanto a la tabla asociativa  sería bueno establecer un índice de unicidad a través del cual controles que no se repita más de un libro con el mismo id de libro, de categoría, de editorial, de carrera en una sola fila...

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48f878/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE libro
    (`libro_id` int, `libro_titulo` varchar(70) )
;

INSERT INTO libro
    (`libro_id`, `libro_titulo`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tras las huellas de José'),
    (2, '¿Por qué no construimos puentes sobre ríos?'),
    (3, 'Menón')
;

CREATE TABLE carrera
    (`carrera_id` int, `carrera_nom` varchar(70) )
;

INSERT INTO carrera
    (`carrera_id`, `carrera_nom`  )
VALUES 
    (1, "Filosofía"),
    (2, "Ingeniería")
;



CREATE TABLE categoria
    (`categoria_id` int, `categoria_nom` varchar(70) )
;

INSERT INTO categoria
    (`categoria_id`,  `categoria_nom` )
VALUES
    (1, "Categoria A"),
    (2, "Categoría B")
;


CREATE TABLE editorial
    (`editorial_id` int, `editorial_nom` varchar(70) )
;

INSERT INTO editorial
    (`editorial_id`, `editorial_nom` )

VALUES
    (1, "Ingenieros Asoc"),
    (2, "Kerygma")
;    


CREATE TABLE asociativa
    (`id` int, `libro_id` int, `carrera_id` int, 
     `categoria_id` int, `editorial_id` int )
;

INSERT INTO asociativa
    (`id`, `libro_id`, `carrera_id`, 
     `categoria_id`, `editorial_id` )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 1, 2, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
#Todos los libros
SELECT
  li.libro_titulo, ca.carrera_nom, ct.categoria_nom, ed.editorial_nom
FROM
  asociativa ta 

  LEFT JOIN libro li ON ta.libro_id=li.libro_id
  LEFT JOIN carrera ca ON ta.carrera_id=ca.carrera_id
  LEFT JOIN categoria ct ON ta.categoria_id=ct.categoria_id
  LEFT JOIN editorial ed ON ta.editorial_id=ed.editorial_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48f878/3/0)**:

```
|                                libro_titulo | carrera_nom | categoria_nom |   editorial_nom |
|---------------------------------------------|-------------|---------------|-----------------|
| ¿Por qué no construimos puentes sobre ríos? |   Filosofía |   Categoría B | Ingenieros Asoc |
|                    Tras las huellas de José |  Ingeniería |   Categoria A |         Kerygma |
```

**Query 2**:

```
#Por Carrera
SELECT
  li.libro_titulo, ca.carrera_nom, ct.categoria_nom, ed.editorial_nom
FROM
  asociativa ta 

  LEFT JOIN libro li ON ta.libro_id=li.libro_id
  LEFT JOIN carrera ca ON ta.carrera_id=ca.carrera_id
  LEFT JOIN categoria ct ON ta.categoria_id=ct.categoria_id
  LEFT JOIN editorial ed ON ta.editorial_id=ed.editorial_id

  WHERE ca.carrera_id=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48f878/3/1)**:

```
|                                libro_titulo | carrera_nom | categoria_nom |   editorial_nom |
|---------------------------------------------|-------------|---------------|-----------------|
| ¿Por qué no construimos puentes sobre ríos? |   Filosofía |   Categoría B | Ingenieros Asoc |
```

Comment: Sin dar mas detalles lo comprendiste y si es así la consulta que yo quiero que cuando ingrese la carrera Ej: Ingeniería me arroje el buscador todos los que correspondan a esa búsqueda, aunque en este caso tu creaste la tabla asociativa con todos los ids de las otras tablas para asi anidarlas verdad?   en mi caso la tabla que yo tengo es idficha y ahi dentro tengo todos mis ids.

Comment: @KevinDuarte Es correcto. Puedes adaptar el modelo con las relaciones que necesites. Lo bueno de este modelo es su flexibilidad, al tener los datos agrupados en cada tabla. Además acepta relaciones de cualquier otro tipo. Suponte que quieras saber también la ciudad en que se editó el libro: sólo creas una tabla ciudad y la relacionas con la tabla editorial y agregas un `JOIN` con esas dos tablas pudiendo así traer la columna `ciudad_nom`a los resultados de tu consulta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! enverdad lo hare asi lo adaptare y vere como queda, encerio me aclaraste las cosas Gracias!

Comment: @KevinDuarte Me alegro. Para que la pregunta no quede abierta, si quieres, marca el cotejo de la izquierda (cerca de donde hay una flecha para arriba y otra para abajo... esas dos flechas sirven para votar positivamente las respuestas, flecha hacia arriba, o negativamente, flecha hacia abajo. Si surgen dudas de otro tipo nada más vuelve por SO y seguro que alguien te ayudará. Saludos.

Comment: buena y completa respuesta